# PHP preg_match - matching html elements

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing, preg-match

Ok so I have a regular expression I'm trying to use to match a certain pattern in some html files. Here's the preg_match statement:

```
preg_match('@<'.$htmlElementType.' id\s*=\s*"{{ALViewElement_'.$this->_elementId.'}}".*>[\s\S]*</'.$htmlElementType.'(>)@i', $htmlString, $newMatches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)
```

To be clear, this is attempting to match an html element with an id of {{ALViewElement_.*}} but it also needs to end itself with a closing tag, for example  if $htmlElementType was "section" it would end in "/section>".

If my html looked just like this with nothing else in it, it works as expected:

```
<section id="{{ALViewElement_resume}}">
            <!--{{RESUME_ADD_CHANGE_PIECE}}-->
            <!--{{RESUME}}-->
        </section>
```

The problem is when we have a section element later in the html and it ALSO has a closing /section>. Example:

```
<section id="{{ALViewElement_resume}}">
            <!--{{RESUME_ADD_CHANGE_PIECE}}-->
            <!--{{RESUME}}-->
        </section>
        <div>

        </div>
        <section>
            HEY THIS IS ME
        </section>
```

In this case the full mach is everything above. But I want it to stop at the  that opens my first one. This is important because later on in my code I need the location of the last > in that ending tag.

Any ideas how I could change this regular expression a little bit?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use an ungreedy quantifier:

```
preg_match('@<'.$htmlElementType.' id\s*=\s*"{{ALViewElement_'.$this->_elementId.'}}".*?>[\s\S]*?</'.$htmlElementType.'(>)@i', $htmlString, $newMatches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)
```

another way: with DOMDocument:

```
$html = <<<LOD
<section id="{{ALViewElement_resume}}">
        <!--{{RESUME_ADD_CHANGE_PIECE}}-->
        <!--{{RESUME}}-->
</section>
<div>

</div>
<section>
    HEY THIS IS ME
</section>
LOD;
$doc= new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$node = $doc->getElementById("{{ALViewElement_resume}}");

$docv = new DOMDocument();
$docv->appendChild($docv->importNode($node, TRUE));
$result = $docv->saveHTML();
echo htmlspecialchars($result);
```

Comment: Awesome. Didn't even know such a thing existed. Thanks!